# PS 1.7 - Validate email in registration form

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I´m looking for function in PS 1.7 core, which is responsible for validating if there is not already Customer account in PS database with same email and is_guest=0. I'm not able to find it.

My issue is, that from time to time, some customers have duplicate Customers accounts (customers - not guest) with same default group, is_guest set to 0 and because of this, they are probably not able to finish their orders (probably, I'm not sure, it's only first suggestion).

Answer (score 0):

Check Customer.php class inside the classes folder. I think you are talking about **customerExists()** function.